# Random natural movement jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, raphael

How can I recreate this type movement with jquery for images: http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-video-12805249-moving-particles-loop-soft-green-hd-1080.php

I'm planning to use it as a web page background. If it is not possible with jquery I'll go with flash as3. But I prefer jquery.

Comment: [ **Raphael** ](http://raphaeljs.com/) might be better suited for this than jQuery.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:**  **[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/index.html)** is definitely better suited for this, since it supports IE. The problem with jQuery is that the rounded corners are a pain to do in IE due to CSS constraints... in Raphael cross browser circles are no sweat.

### **[jsFiddle with Raphael - all browsers](http://fiddle.jshell.net/DYN6U/show/light/)**:

(though it might look nicer **[speeded up in IE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bTBAZ/show/light/)**)

```
(function() {
    var paper, circs, i, nowX, nowY, timer, props = {}, toggler = 0, elie, dx, dy, rad, cur, opa;
    // Returns a random integer between min and max  
    // Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!  
    function ran(min, max)  
    {  
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;  
    } 

    function moveIt()
    {
        for(i = 0; i < circs.length; ++i)
        {            
              // Reset when time is at zero
            if (! circs[i].time) 
            {
                circs[i].time  = ran(30, 100);
                circs[i].deg   = ran(-179, 180);
                circs[i].vel   = ran(1, 5);  
                circs[i].curve = ran(0, 1);
                circs[i].fade  = ran(0, 1);
                circs[i].grow  = ran(-2, 2); 
            }                
                // Get position
            nowX = circs[i].attr("cx");
            nowY = circs[i].attr("cy");   
               // Calc movement
            dx = circs[i].vel * Math.cos(circs[i].deg * Math.PI/180);
            dy = circs[i].vel * Math.sin(circs[i].deg * Math.PI/180);
                // Calc new position
            nowX += dx;
            nowY += dy;
                // Calc wrap around
            if (nowX < 0) nowX = 490 + nowX;
            else          nowX = nowX % 490;            
            if (nowY < 0) nowY = 490 + nowY;
            else          nowY = nowY % 490;

                // Render moved particle
            circs[i].attr({cx: nowX, cy: nowY});

                // Calc growth
            rad = circs[i].attr("r");
            if (circs[i].grow > 0) circs[i].attr("r", Math.min(30, rad +  .1));
            else                   circs[i].attr("r", Math.max(10,  rad -  .1));

                // Calc curve
            if (circs[i].curve > 0) circs[i].deg = circs[i].deg + 2;
            else                    circs[i].deg = circs[i].deg - 2;

                // Calc opacity
            opa = circs[i].attr("fill-opacity");
            if (circs[i].fade > 0) {
                circs[i].attr("fill-opacity", Math.max(.3, opa -  .01));
                circs[i].attr("stroke-opacity", Math.max(.3, opa -  .01)); }
            else {
                circs[i].attr("fill-opacity", Math.min(1, opa +  .01));
                circs[i].attr("stroke-opacity", Math.min(1, opa +  .01)); }

            // Progress timer for particle
            circs[i].time = circs[i].time - 1;

                // Calc damping
            if (circs[i].vel < 1) circs[i].time = 0;
            else circs[i].vel = circs[i].vel - .05;              

        } 
        timer = setTimeout(moveIt, 60);
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        paper = Raphael("canvas", 500, 500);
        circs = paper.set();
        for (i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
        {
            opa = ran(3,10)/10;
            circs.push(paper.circle(ran(0,500), ran(0,500), ran(10,30)).attr({"fill-opacity": opa,
                                                                           "stroke-opacity": opa}));
        }
        circs.attr({fill: "#00DDAA", stroke: "#00DDAA"});
        moveIt();
        elie = document.getElementById("toggle");
        elie.onclick = function() {
            (toggler++ % 2) ? (function(){
                    moveIt();
                    elie.value = " Stop ";
                }()) : (function(){
                    clearTimeout(timer);
                    elie.value = " Start ";
                }());
        }
    };
}());​
```

---

The first attempt jQuery solution is below:

---

This jQuery attempt pretty much failes in IE and is slow in FF. Chrome and Safari do well:

### **[jsFiddle example for all browsers (IE is not that good)](http://jsfiddle.net/PppZ3/)**

(I didn't implement the fade in IE, and IE doesn't have rounded corners... also the JS is slower, so it looks pretty bad overall)

[jsFiddle example for Chrome and Safari only (4x more particles)](http://jsfiddle.net/Y73pU/)

```
(function() {
    var x, y, $elie, pos, nowX, nowY, i, $that, vel, deg, fade, curve, ko, mo, oo, grow, len;

    // Returns a random integer between min and max  
    // Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!  
    function ran(min, max)  
    {  
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;  
    } 

    function moveIt()
    {
        $("div.spec").each(function(i, v) {
            $elie = $(v);
            if (! $elie.data("time"))
            {
                $elie.data("time", ran(30, 100));
                $elie.data("deg", ran(-179, 180));
                $elie.data("vel", ran(3, 10));  
                $elie.data("curve", ran(0, 1));
                $elie.data("fade", ran(0, 1));
                $elie.data("grow", ran(-2, 2));                
            }

            vel = $elie.data("vel");
            deg = $elie.data("deg");
            fade = $elie.data("fade");            
            curve = $elie.data("curve");
            grow = $elie.data("grow");

            len = $elie.width();
            if (grow > 0)
                len = Math.min(len + grow, 50);
            else
                len = Math.max(len + grow, 20);

            $elie.css("-moz-border-radius", len/2);
            $elie.css("border-radius", len/2);

            $elie.css("width", len);
            $elie.css("height", len);

            pos = $elie.position();            

            $elie.data("time", $elie.data("time") - 1);

            if (curve)
                $elie.data("deg", (deg + 5) % 180);
            else
                $elie.data("deg", (deg - 5) % 180);

            ko = $elie.css("-khtml-opacity");
            mo = $elie.css("-moz-opacity");
            oo = $elie.css("opacity");
            if (fade)
            {
                $elie.css("-khtml-opacity", Math.max(ko - .1, .5));
                $elie.css("-moz-opacity", Math.max(mo - .1, .5));
                $elie.css("opacity", Math.max(oo - .1, .5));
            } else
            {
                $elie.css("-khtml-opacity", Math.min(ko - -.1, 1));
                $elie.css("-moz-opacity", Math.min(mo - -.1, 1));
                $elie.css("opacity", Math.min(oo - -.1, 1));                
            }

            if (vel < 3)
                $elie.data("time", 0);
            else
                $elie.data("vel", vel - .2);            


            nowX = pos.left;
            nowY = pos.top;

            x = vel * Math.cos(deg * Math.PI/180);
            y = vel * Math.sin(deg * Math.PI/180);

            nowX = nowX + x;            
            nowY = nowY + y;

            if (nowX < 0)
                nowX = 490 + nowX;
            else
                nowX = nowX % 490;

            if (nowY < 0)
                nowY = 490 + nowY;
            else
                nowY = nowY % 490;            
            $elie.css("left", nowX);
            $elie.css("top",  nowY);
        });
    }
    $(function() {
        $(document.createElement('div')).appendTo('body').attr('id', 'box');
        $elie = $("<div/>").attr("class","spec");
        // Note that math random is inclussive for 0 and exclussive for Max
        for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            $that = $elie.clone();  
            $that.css("top", ran(0, 495));
            $that.css("left", ran(0, 495));            
            $("#box").append($that);            
        }          
        timer = setInterval(moveIt, 60);
        $("input").toggle(function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
            this.value = " Start ";
        }, function() {
            timer = setInterval(moveIt, 60);        
            this.value = " Stop ";            
        });        
    });
}());
​
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed but too slow, probably flash will do better as background.

Comment: @Hasan - I just tried it in Raphael (edited it into answer) - It defnitely looks nicer in IE. You can play around with the particle properties to speed it up and such.

Comment: could this be applied to letters or numbers? (instead of circles)

Comment: @Toni - Sure. Just create an array of letters or numbers instead of circles. You can put them in divs or use Raphael to make them.

Answer (score 4):

[Partial answer, just for the physics.]

[I just saw the previous answer, mine is somewhat along the same lines.]

You may try to simulate some sort of Brownian motion, i.e. a movement deriving
from the combination of a random force and a viscous damping. Pseudocode:

```
initialize:
    x = random_position();
    v_x = random_velocity();  // v_x = velocity along x
    // and same for y
for (each time step) {
    x += v_x;
    v_x += random_force() - time_step / damping_time * v_x;
    // and same for y
}
```

Keep the damping time long (~ 1 second) and the amplitude of the random force small. Otherwise the movement may be too jerky.

For an easy to implement Gaussian random number generator, look up Box-Muller in Wikipedia.

Comment: have a read of: [editing-help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/), it'll explain how to use the markdown editor to format code so that it appears legible in your answers (as well as some other useful stuff, too). Also, +1.

Comment: you've been here (perhaps less than) a day, asked no questions and posted a good answer 'just for the physics' =) **awesome** start! And, also, welcome to Stackoverflow =D

Answer (score 2):

For the mathematics of it, you give every object a starting position and velocity.  The "random walk" is achieved by computing a random angle that is constrained by some amount (experiment).  Then change the angle of the velocity vector by this angle.  You can also compute a random speed delta and change the magnitude of the vector by that amount.  Because you're working with velocity, the movements will be somewhat smooth.  A slightly more advanced approach to to work with acceleration directly and compute velocity and position based off that.

For your random steering value, a binomial distribution is preferable to a uniform one.  Binomial distributions are concentrated around 0 instead of uniformly spread out.  You can just do random() - random() (psuedocode)

Vector math is extensively documented but if you run into a snag, leave a comment.

Comment: I must keep it as simple as I can. Here is a similar animation technique.: http://robot.anthonycalzadilla.com/ I just need to move the clouds x and y axis and make them invisible after a random time period.

Comment: This really is as simple as it gets.  You're simulating position and velocity and changing direction (acceleration).  You want it to be random (ie not a video) so you have to compute random numbers to affect these properties.

Answer (score 1):

very late answer from my side, but I thought I might give an approach...

I personally would use an svg vector image.
Create a jquery plugin which accepts opacity, size. and makes them move in a random direction.
Then do a javascript loop in creating a set of those particles (where opacity and size are random, plus the start location is random)
Then make the jquery plugin to initiate a new instance of itself when the particle is unloaded.

(If you look at the little movie you will see that they move in 1 direction and fade out, then another fades in.)

The opacity effect will give the depth perspective.

Not sure if my answer helps, but I would go in that direction.